# CMake does not support toolset specification

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to build the Checked-C project which uses CMake, but when I go to generate the makefile CMake gives the following error.

```
~/checkedc/build$ cmake ../llvm
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:57 (project):
  Generator

     Unix Makefiles

  does not support toolset specification, but toolset

    host=x64

  was specified.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I have CMake version 3.9.1 installed along with GNU Make 4.1, Clang 5, and GCC 7. Anyone able to tell me what this CMake error means?

That section of CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
57 project(LLVM
58  ${cmake_3_0_PROJ_VERSION}
59  ${cmake_3_0_LANGUAGES}
60  C CXX ASM)
```

I've tried setting C/CXX/ASM but get the same error:

```
~/checkedc/build$ cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="clang-5.0" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="clang-5.0" -DCMAKE_ASM_COMPILER="clang-5.0" ../llvm
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:57 (project):
  Generator

    Unix Makefiles

   does not support toolset specification, but toolset
 
    host=x64

   was specified.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I'm on Kubuntu 17.10 64bit.

EDIT:

You can find the project and CMakeList.txt here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/checkedc-clang

Comment: What is the repo for the LLVM you're trying to build? Are there specific instructions for Checked-C? Please [edit] the question adding that info.

Comment: who says he's trying to build LLVM?  What they should do is provide the root CMakeList.txt file for us at least so we know what variables they are setting.

Answer (score 2):

It means that somewhere in CMake files the variable `CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET` is set to `host=x64`. This setting only makes sense for Visual Studio generator so CMake opts to throw an error in this case.

To fix it double check the setup for your OS and generator. If this doesn't help then you'll need to find where this variable is set and remove this line.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and I think a combination of two things solved the problem. (a) I chose a different build directory and (b) this command

`cmake -S src -B debug -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=<path to toolchain file>`