# Building LLVM with CMake error: NMake Makefiles does not support toolset specification

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, windows-10, llvm, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to build LLVM on Windows 10 using [this tutorial](https://llvm.org/docs/GettingStartedVS.html) from the LLVM docs.

However, CMake gives the error `NMake Makefiles does not support toolset specification, but toolset host=x64 was specified`, which I have sadly been unable to surmount.

## Error:

In the VS2022 developer prompt, I get to **configure LLVM using CMake** (step #12), which results in the following error:

```
C:\Users\Name\Documents\name\code\tools\llvm> cmake -S .\llvm -B build -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=clang -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=X86

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:44 (project):
  Generator

    NMake Makefiles

  does not support toolset specification, but toolset

    host=x64

  was specified.


CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

See also "C:/Users/Name/Documents/name/code/tools/llvm/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

And `CMakeOutput.log` simply reads:

```
The system is: Windows - 10.0.19042 - AMD64
```

### Attempts at remediation:

I referred to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52175666/cmake-does-not-support-toolset-specification) but was unclear as to what to do.
Line 44 simply consists of:

```
project(LLVM
  VERSION ${LLVM_VERSION_MAJOR}.${LLVM_VERSION_MINOR}.${LLVM_VERSION_PATCH}
  LANGUAGES C CXX ASM)
```

Again, thank you very much in advance for any help on this issue!

### Update #1

As per [tsyvarev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3440745/tsyvarev)'s suggestion, I tried: `cmake -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -A x64 -S .\llvm -B build -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=clang -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=X86 -Thost=x64`

This results in:

```
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22000.0 to target Windows 10.0.19042.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.30.30705.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.30.30705.0
-- The ASM compiler identification is MSVC
-- Found assembler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.30.30705/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.30.30705/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.30.30705/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- clang project is enabled
-- clang-tools-extra project is disabled
-- compiler-rt project is disabled
-- cross-project-tests project is disabled
-- libc project is disabled
-- libclc project is disabled
-- libcxx project is disabled
-- libcxxabi project is disabled
-- libunwind project is disabled
-- lld project is disabled
-- lldb project is disabled
-- mlir project is disabled
-- openmp project is disabled
-- polly project is disabled
-- pstl project is disabled
-- flang project is disabled
-- Looking for dlfcn.h
-- Looking for dlfcn.h - not found
-- Looking for errno.h
-- Looking for errno.h - found
-- Looking for fcntl.h
-- Looking for fcntl.h - found
-- Looking for link.h
-- Looking for link.h - not found
-- Looking for malloc/malloc.h
-- Looking for malloc/malloc.h - not found
-- Looking for signal.h
-- Looking for signal.h - found
-- Looking for sys/ioctl.h
-- Looking for sys/ioctl.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/mman.h
-- Looking for sys/mman.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/param.h
-- Looking for sys/param.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/resource.h
-- Looking for sys/resource.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/stat.h
-- Looking for sys/stat.h - found
-- Looking for sys/time.h
-- Looking for sys/time.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for sysexits.h
-- Looking for sysexits.h - not found
-- Looking for termios.h
-- Looking for termios.h - not found
-- Looking for unistd.h
-- Looking for unistd.h - not found
-- Looking for valgrind/valgrind.h
-- Looking for valgrind/valgrind.h - not found
-- Looking for fenv.h
-- Looking for fenv.h - found
-- Looking for FE_ALL_EXCEPT
-- Looking for FE_ALL_EXCEPT - found
-- Looking for FE_INEXACT
-- Looking for FE_INEXACT - found
-- Looking for mach/mach.h
-- Looking for mach/mach.h - not found
-- Looking for histedit.h
-- Looking for histedit.h - not found
-- Looking for CrashReporterClient.h
-- Looking for CrashReporterClient.h - not found
-- Looking for pfm_initialize in pfm
-- Looking for pfm_initialize in pfm - not found
-- Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY) (found version "1.2.11")
-- Could NOT find LibXml2 (missing: LIBXML2_LIBRARY) (found version "2.9.9")
-- Looking for xar_open in xar
-- Looking for xar_open in xar - not found
-- Looking for arc4random
-- Looking for arc4random - not found
-- Looking for backtrace
-- Looking for backtrace - not found
-- Could NOT find Backtrace (missing: Backtrace_LIBRARY Backtrace_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Performing Test C_SUPPORTS_WERROR_UNGUARDED_AVAILABILITY_NEW
-- Performing Test C_SUPPORTS_WERROR_UNGUARDED_AVAILABILITY_NEW - Failed
-- Looking for __register_frame
-- Looking for __register_frame - not found
-- Looking for __deregister_frame
-- Looking for __deregister_frame - not found
-- Looking for __unw_add_dynamic_fde
-- Looking for __unw_add_dynamic_fde - not found
-- Looking for _Unwind_Backtrace
-- Looking for _Unwind_Backtrace - not found
-- Looking for getpagesize
-- Looking for getpagesize - not found
-- Looking for sysconf
-- Looking for sysconf - not found
-- Looking for getrusage
-- Looking for getrusage - not found
-- Looking for setrlimit
-- Looking for setrlimit - not found
-- Looking for isatty
-- Looking for isatty - not found
-- Looking for futimens
-- Looking for futimens - not found
-- Looking for futimes
-- Looking for futimes - not found
-- Looking for posix_fallocate
-- Looking for posix_fallocate - not found
-- Looking for sigaltstack
-- Looking for sigaltstack - not found
-- Looking for lseek64
-- Looking for lseek64 - not found
-- Looking for mallctl
-- Looking for mallctl - not found
-- Looking for mallinfo
-- Looking for mallinfo - not found
-- Looking for mallinfo2
-- Looking for mallinfo2 - not found
-- Looking for malloc_zone_statistics
-- Looking for malloc_zone_statistics - not found
-- Looking for getrlimit
-- Looking for getrlimit - not found
-- Looking for posix_spawn
-- Looking for posix_spawn - not found
-- Looking for pread
-- Looking for pread - not found
-- Looking for sbrk
-- Looking for sbrk - not found
-- Looking for strerror
-- Looking for strerror - found
-- Looking for strerror_r
-- Looking for strerror_r - not found
-- Looking for strerror_s
-- Looking for strerror_s - found
-- Looking for setenv
-- Looking for setenv - not found
-- Looking for _chsize_s
-- Looking for _chsize_s - found
-- Looking for _alloca
-- Looking for _alloca - not found
-- Looking for __alloca
-- Looking for __alloca - not found
-- Looking for __chkstk
-- Looking for __chkstk - found
-- Looking for __chkstk_ms
-- Looking for __chkstk_ms - not found
-- Looking for ___chkstk
-- Looking for ___chkstk - not found
-- Looking for ___chkstk_ms
-- Looking for ___chkstk_ms - not found
-- Looking for __ashldi3
-- Looking for __ashldi3 - not found
-- Looking for __ashrdi3
-- Looking for __ashrdi3 - not found
-- Looking for __divdi3
-- Looking for __divdi3 - not found
-- Looking for __fixdfdi
-- Looking for __fixdfdi - not found
-- Looking for __fixsfdi
-- Looking for __fixsfdi - not found
-- Looking for __floatdidf
-- Looking for __floatdidf - not found
-- Looking for __lshrdi3
-- Looking for __lshrdi3 - not found
-- Looking for __moddi3
-- Looking for __moddi3 - not found
-- Looking for __udivdi3
-- Looking for __udivdi3 - not found
-- Looking for __umoddi3
-- Looking for __umoddi3 - not found
-- Looking for __main
-- Looking for __main - not found
-- Looking for __cmpdi2
-- Looking for __cmpdi2 - not found
-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_MTIMESPEC_TV_NSEC
-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_MTIMESPEC_TV_NSEC - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_MTIM_TV_NSEC
-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_MTIM_TV_NSEC - Failed
-- Looking for __GLIBC__
-- Looking for __GLIBC__ - not found
-- Looking for proc_pid_rusage
-- Looking for proc_pid_rusage - not found
-- Performing Test HAVE_STD_IS_TRIVIALLY_COPYABLE
-- Performing Test HAVE_STD_IS_TRIVIALLY_COPYABLE - Success
-- Performing Test LLVM_HAS_ATOMICS
-- Performing Test LLVM_HAS_ATOMICS - Success
-- Performing Test SUPPORTS_VARIADIC_MACROS_FLAG
-- Performing Test SUPPORTS_VARIADIC_MACROS_FLAG - Failed
-- Performing Test SUPPORTS_GNU_ZERO_VARIADIC_MACRO_ARGUMENTS_FLAG
-- Performing Test SUPPORTS_GNU_ZERO_VARIADIC_MACRO_ARGUMENTS_FLAG - Failed
-- Native target architecture is X86
-- Threads enabled.
-- Doxygen disabled.
-- Go bindings disabled.
-- Could NOT find OCaml (missing: OCAMLFIND OCAML_VERSION OCAML_STDLIB_PATH)
-- OCaml bindings disabled.
-- Could NOT find Python module pygments
-- Could NOT find Python module pygments.lexers.c_cpp
-- Could NOT find Python module yaml
-- LLVM host triple: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
-- LLVM default target triple: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
-- Using Debug VC++ CRT: MDd
-- Using Release VC++ CRT: MD
-- Using MinSizeRel VC++ CRT: MD
-- Using RelWithDebInfo VC++ CRT: MD
-- Looking for os_signpost_interval_begin
-- Looking for os_signpost_interval_begin - not found
-- Found Python3: C:/Users/Name/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe (found suitable version "3.9.5", minimum required is "3.6") found components: Interpreter
-- Performing Test HAS_WERROR_GLOBAL_CTORS
-- Performing Test HAS_WERROR_GLOBAL_CTORS - Failed
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1008 (add_subdirectory):
  add_subdirectory given source "utils/TableGen" which is not an existing
  directory.


CMake Error at cmake/modules/TableGen.cmake:9 (message):
  LLVM_TABLEGEN_EXE not set
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  include/llvm/IR/CMakeLists.txt:2 (tablegen)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/Name/Documents/name/code/tools/llvm/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/Name/Documents/name/code/tools/llvm/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: The first sentence of the tutorial you follow is "This document only covers LLVM on Windows using **Visual Studio**". But according to the error message, the [generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) **NMake Makefiles** is used, which seems to be default CMake generator on your system. You could explicitly specify a generator in the command line using option `-G Visual Studio 17 2022`.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me!  I tried what you said but was unsuccessful; OP updated with results.

Comment: In the repository, under `llvm` directory there is `utils/TableGen` directory: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/main/llvm/utils/TableGen. Check that you have given directory too.

Comment: It is there.  But CMake seems to be unable to locate it.  I'm running it from inside `llvm-project\llvm\`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, the difference was that I was using vs2019

By comparison, I found that in the repo on github,

https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/main/llvm/utils and

https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/main/utils

The content in it is different from that of my local folder.

I don't understand why, but when I do the copy: `D:\llvm\utils` => `D:\llvm\llvm\utils`

Everything works fine and the output is as follows：

```sh
❯ cmake -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=clang -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64 -Thost=x64 ..\llvm
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19044.
-- bolt project is disabled
-- clang project is enabled
-- clang-tools-extra project is disabled
-- compiler-rt project is disabled
-- cross-project-tests project is disabled
-- libc project is disabled
-- libclc project is disabled
-- libcxx project is disabled
-- libcxxabi project is disabled
-- libunwind project is disabled
-- lld project is disabled
-- lldb project is disabled
-- mlir project is disabled
-- openmp project is disabled
-- polly project is disabled
-- pstl project is disabled
-- flang project is disabled
-- Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY) (found version "1.2.11")
-- Could NOT find LibXml2 (missing: LIBXML2_LIBRARY LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find Backtrace (missing: Backtrace_LIBRARY Backtrace_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Native target architecture is X86
-- Threads enabled.
-- Doxygen disabled.
-- Go bindings disabled.
-- Could NOT find OCaml (missing: OCAMLFIND OCAML_VERSION OCAML_STDLIB_PATH)
-- OCaml bindings disabled.
-- LLVM host triple: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
-- LLVM default target triple: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
-- Using Debug VC++ CRT: MDd
-- Using Release VC++ CRT: MD
-- Using MinSizeRel VC++ CRT: MD
-- Using RelWithDebInfo VC++ CRT: MD
-- Found Git: C:/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe (found version "2.27.0.windows.1")
-- LLVMHello ignored -- Loadable modules not supported on this platform.
-- Targeting AArch64
-- Targeting AMDGPU
-- Targeting ARM
-- Targeting AVR
-- Targeting BPF
-- Targeting Hexagon
-- Targeting Lanai
-- Targeting Mips
-- Targeting MSP430
-- Targeting NVPTX
-- Targeting PowerPC
-- Targeting RISCV
-- Targeting Sparc
-- Targeting SystemZ
-- Targeting VE
-- Targeting WebAssembly
-- Targeting X86
-- Targeting XCore
-- Looking for sys/resource.h
-- Looking for sys/resource.h - not found
-- Clang version: 14.0.0
-- Not building amdgpu-arch: hsa-runtime64 not found
-- PrintFunctionNames ignored -- Loadable modules not supported on this platform.
-- AnnotateFunctions ignored -- Loadable modules not supported on this platform.
-- Attribute ignored -- Loadable modules not supported on this platform.
-- CallSuperAttr ignored -- Loadable modules not supported on this platform.
-- PluginsOrder ignored -- Loadable modules not supported on this platform.
-- BugpointPasses ignored -- Loadable modules not supported on this platform.
-- git version: v0.0.0-dirty normalized to 0.0.0
-- Version: 1.6.0
-- Looking for shm_open in rt
-- Looking for shm_open in rt - not found
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FLAG_EHS_
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FLAG_EHS_ - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FLAG_EHA_
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FLAG_EHA_ - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_GNU_POSIX_REGEX
-- Performing Test HAVE_GNU_POSIX_REGEX
-- Performing Test HAVE_GNU_POSIX_REGEX -- failed to compile
-- Performing Test HAVE_POSIX_REGEX
-- Performing Test HAVE_POSIX_REGEX
-- Performing Test HAVE_POSIX_REGEX -- failed to compile
CMake Warning at D:/llvm/third-party/benchmark/CMakeLists.txt:308 (message):
  Using std::regex with exceptions disabled is not fully supported


-- Performing Test HAVE_STEADY_CLOCK
-- Performing Test HAVE_STEADY_CLOCK
-- Performing Test HAVE_STEADY_CLOCK -- success
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread - yes
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/llvm/build
```

By the way, I noticed a similar problem
https://cxuesong.com/archives/1056
It is mentioned here:
 `Obviously, they decided to exclude this part of the feature in the packed installer.`
Perhaps for the same reason? I do not know.

update:

If you use `Download ZIP` then there is no problem of folder contents being different from repo.

But I'm getting tens of thousands of compile errors, not sure if it's because I use vcpkg install llvm12, I'll try it later.

update2:
Build succeeded[image]

Answer (score 1):

I encountered similar issues, and [found a comment on the MSDN blog site](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/clang-llvm-support-in-visual-studio/comment-page-2/#comment-570):

> It’s better to mention that the toolset name working with cmake is “ClangCL”. I’ve tried clang-cl, clang, llvm. None of them works untils I’ve found this page https://tracker.dev.opencascade.org/view.php?id=31060 mentioning the “ClangCL”

And the follow-up comment to it from Tim Hutton [MSFT]:

> And for 64-bit builds, set the CMake toolset to ‘ClangCL,host=x64’ https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET.html

Sure enough, using `-T ClangCL,host=x64` in the cmake command line worked for me.